# How do I use counting related instances instead of attributes in OCL

Tags: collections, attributes, uml, ocl

For example say if I had a library and a precondition of issuing a book to a borrower was that it can only be issued if it is not reference only and is not already on loan to someone else, I could say:

```
context Copy::issue() : Boolean
    pre: (referenceCopy and onLoan) == false
```

But that would use the attribute onLoan for the book copy. Instead I want to say this with collection-methods to count related entities?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use isEmpty()

```
context Copy::issue() : Boolean
    pre: not self.referenceCopy and self.borrowers->isEmpty()
```

or count()

```
context Copy::issue() : Boolean
    pre: not self.referenceCopy and self.borrowers->count() = 0
```

You can omit the context variable *self* if you want.